# Is there a way I can access the local variables of a method in a different script by using Reflection to get the method using a string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reflection

I'm using the latest recommended version of Unity and I'm trying to access an array of strings localized in a method in a different script. I want to be able to access the method by using the GetMethod function in the System.Reflection library. There aren't any compiler errors in my script but whenever I try to test the game, Unity freezes. This is what I have so far:

```
preMaps = GetComponent<PreMaps>();
MethodInfo Method = preMaps.GetType().GetMethod(mapName);
Method.Invoke(preMaps, null);
foreach (LocalVariableInfo variable in Method.GetMethodBody().LocalVariables)
{
    print(variable);
}
```

I simply put a print line to test if I was getting any variables out of the method and I previously declared the preMaps variable as a PreMaps class at the beginning of the script. The mapName variable is a string that matches the name of a method in the other script (previously declared and initialized). Is there anything that I'm missing? I've tested it without these lines and Unity doesn't freeze.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PreMaps : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class MapName
    {
        public readonly static string[] map = {
        "p,250,110,50,184,10",
        "start,10",
        "n,0,0,0,100",
        "fin"
        };
    }
}
```

This is all that's in the other script I'm trying to access.

Comment: You have not shown us the function whose variable you want to extract. The variable will not exist unless the function is actively running. And there will be a seperate version for each execution. Why not simply put this variable outside the function, given that clearly it has uses outside the function?

Comment: If you start using reflection just to access static variables you're going to have a bad time. Reflection is performance intensive, avoid it whenever possible in your games especially with Unity. You cant use GetMethod to get a variable, only methods. Put them in a static constants class and just access them directly. If you're dead set on using Reflection, which I urge you not to be, you need to use GetProperty()

Comment: ok, I'll try that but I wanted to be able to organize them in classes just in case I wanted to add other variables to each map.

Comment: Good to know @TheBatman, I'll try to avoid using that library.

Comment: There's a chance I might just use a switch statement to pull out whichever variable I want, that seems like the easiest way.

Comment: This question reads like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreMaps.MapName` is a **CLASS** (Type), not a *Method*!

And `PreMaps.MapName.map` is a **FIELD** within that class, not a *LocalVariable*!

---

Anyway I see no need for / sense in using Reflection **at all**!

All your types and their fields are `public` anyway so as far as I can tell there is absolutely nothing that hinders you from simply doing

```
foreach (var mapValue in PreMaps.MapName.map)
{
    Debug.Log(mapValue);
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this in the end with a switch block that matched each song name to each variable. Thanks for the input.